# How do I force ASP:TextBox to be of type email?

Tags: asp.net, html, validation

I have an `ASP.NET 3.5` application and I'd like to add the `type="email"` according to `HTML5` standards but if I add the type on the `ASP:TextBox` control I get the below output:

```
<input name="ctl00$content$txtEmailAddress" type="text" type="email" value="" 
id="ctl00_content_txtEmailAddress" class="input-block-level" required="required"/>
```

How can I replace the type attribute from "text" to "email"?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you using .Net 3.5 then no matter what type you have specified with `<asp:TextBox>`, it will always render with `<input type="text" />`. So in that case you can use simple html input with type="email"

```
<input type="email" />
```

For 4.5 version you can use `TextMode="Email"`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtmyBox" runat="server" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: i think TextMode only have MultiLine, SingleLine and Password only, Text mode does not contain the Email mode

Comment: email and number and some others are in 4.5 not in 3.5

Comment: That's exactly what I written in my answer

Comment: Isn't there a way I can do this in 3.5?

Comment: in 3.5 you can just use simple html input control like I mentioned

Comment: The thing about type="email" is that you can do HTML5 validation before posting. I want to keep validations standard.

Comment: in dot.net 4 type="email" does not compile when using runat='server'

Answer (score 6):

Sorry I'm a bit late to the party, though I think that others can benefit from what I did. I have a page which is HTML 5 though we still have .NET 3.5. We wanted to keep the .NET element, though have the type change to email.

I've tried several methods, though the one which worked for me was the following: I added a JavaScript property to the element itself inline (when I put it in a script tag it wouldn't pick up for some reason...)

Here is what your tag would look like if you use my changes:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" type="email" onfocus="this.type='email'"/>
```

Comment: Mighta helped if you included the javascript necessary to get this working.

Comment: @Johnny I did include it...here it is separarely: onfocus="this.type='email'"   what this does is have JavaScript change the "type" to email, onfocus.

Comment: @Eli I think this is a good solution for someone who doesn't have the luxury of upgrading the framework as I did. However, I am also investigating other ways of writing extensions for .NET 3.5 that include helpful and useful functionalities only available in higher .NET versions. I will consider your answer as well. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this actually does anything.. I needed this for devices to get the @ in the keyboard.. even though the type does change on focus, it is not behaving as an email input field (atleast not on ipad)

Comment: btw trying to do this with jquery, I get an error - "cannot change the 'type' attribute"

Comment: @webkit Can you please share the jQuery code which you were using? I tried this on iPhones, in order to get the @ symbol to be there for email addresses, and it worked exactly as expected...

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this..

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="email" />
```

New syntax lets you define a TextBox control that is HTML5 compatible. For example, the following code defines a TextBox control that is HTML5 compatible:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" type="some-HTML5-type" />
```

You can refer this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871 and go to feature 3.

Comment: That is only possible from .NET 4.5 upwards. I have upgraded my application to .NET 4.5 and it's working fine now.

Comment: I did try .NET 4.0 and it was not working. I eventually had to upgrade to .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of .NET you could extend the `TextBox` class with the possibility to set the input type:

A completely basic - but working - solution could be the one shown below, which also adds a placeholder to the textbox.

```
namespace Ux.Example{
    public class TextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
    {
        public string PlaceHolder { get; set; }

        public string InputType { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PlaceHolder))
                Attributes.Add("placeholder", PlaceHolder);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InputType))
            {
                Attributes.Add("type", InputType);
            }
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You would also have to include the file in the aspx file using `@Register`:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ux" Namespace="Ux.Example" Assembly="CHANGE_TO_CORRECT_NAME" %>
```

And the actual usage of the control would then be:

```
<ux:TextBox ID="Email" Visible="false" runat="server" PlaceHolder="enter e-mail address" InputType="email" />
```

I have not tested what happens when the `TextMode` attribute is in use. It may cause some havoc.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but it looks like the right direction. However, won't it give you two `type=` attributes as you are "adding" `type` attribute and not removing what's there before hand?

Comment: I am using it in production somewhere as far as I recall. And I would say: "no" :). I think there is a dictionary involved.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show a preview of email list depend of your characters that you are typing and your history of email names in browser, you should set name of element ID just"email". but all method mostly work on chrome:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" CssClass="YourEmailCss"></asp:TextBox>
```

or, if you use HTML standard elements:

```
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" />
```

Comment: This is not the solution required. That will not work anyway as <asp:TextBox ID="email" ... will also include the container of the control as part of the final ID/Name attributes, and will not match to the collection. You will also need to add the `ClientIDMode="static"` to make it that way.

Having said that, this won't be a valid HTML5 solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (not updating to .Net 4.5) ended up like this with an inline script, the element ID is visible if you inspect the rendered html input element.

```
<label class="input text">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="text" ID="EmailTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_EmailTextBox").type = "email";
    </script>
</label>
```